# Does having more classes necessarily increase the memory requirements of the app?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, memory

When we add .edmx files to a DLL, the physical size of the DLL increases.  DLL's are loaded into memory.  However, the .NET infrastructure with functionality such as JIT compilation and the GAC complicates things.  Is it true that having a larger DLL  automatically increase the memory requirements of an application?

In other words, are memory concerns a good reason to split generated code such as entity framework into N DLL's?

Comment: What code does consumes memory. Not how much code there is.

Comment: Does "memory requirements" refer to the total memory used by the app? Supposing a class is instantiated tens of thousands of times and separating it into two removes an instance variable, having more classes in that case would decrease the total memory used.

Comment: @MatthewFoscarini - Are you saying there is no direct correlation between the physical size of a DLL and how much memory loading said DLL into the appdomain consumes?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the more code you have in the application, the more memory it requires to load all that code when running the application. But

> In other words, are memory concerns a good reason to split generated code such as entity framework into N DLL's?

I would say no. Modern day computer should have more that enough memory to load all the executable code at once. There could be an issue with run-time memory, e.g. if you were to try to cache all the data for an enterprise application in memory. But not the executable code, IMHO.

And splitting it up into several DLLs would not help a lot. You would still require to load all the executable code in order for the application to work. Except if you would load/unload code on demand.

And trying to load/unload code on demand does add extra complexity to the project. This complexity adds cost and risk (which is more cost). E.g. you cannot simply unload a dll in .NET. You have to load it into a separate AppDomain. Then you can unload the AppDomain.

If you really was hitting the memory limit for executable code, upgrading the memory on the computers running the application would most probably be cheaper than implementing loading/unloading of code at runtime.

Comment: "_Modern day computer should have more that enough memory to load all the executable code at once._" That kind of advice waxes and wanes.  Yes, laptops and desktops have multiple GB, and servers much more.  But phones and similar devices are much more constrained.

Comment: +1 for "_And trying to load/unload code on demand does add extra complexity to the project._".  It's how things were always done 40 years ago, when we thought 32KB was a lot of memory, and every program was designed to run in phases and load and unload parts dynamically.  It caused a lot of problems that were solved by virtual memory and large physical memory banks.

Comment: "You would still require to load all the exe..."  Enterprise systems have many databases.  A given application may only use a small subset of them.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Yeah, databases.  The key there is **data**.  That's not the same thing as code, Lisp notwithstanding.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - My point is that ORM's generate code from a database.  If I don't use that generated code, then how much does that unused code (In this case a generated ORM mapping to a set of DB's) impact a .NET application?  This answer does not address this critical point in my question.

Comment: This discussion has made me interested in the following question: In a large-scale application, for instance, a webserver or database, how much memory tends to be used PURELY by the application's code itself? (ie, before main() is called - not including any initializations of objects or variables) My vague impression is that at most, it would be in the area of 50 MB.